# How to use Hive MACRO to reduce boilerplate

Tags: hive, hiveql

My Hive code has the repeating pattern with 15 complex LATER VIEWs.

Below I simplified the explode code for the sake of brevity:

```
SELECT a,b,c,d FROM t
LATERAL VIEW explode(split(regexp(s,'A',''),',')) a as a
LATERAL VIEW explode(split(regexp(s,'B',''),',')) b as b
LATERAL VIEW explode(split(regexp(s,'C',''),',')) c as c
LATERAL VIEW explode(split(regexp(s,'D',''),',')) d as d
...
```

I tried to use MACRO to eliminate typing 15 times the complex explode expression which are very similar (differ only by 1 argument).

I created the following MACRO:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY MACRO explode_me(s string, p string)
  explode(split(regexp(s,p,''),','))
;
SELECT a  FROM t
LATERAL VIEW explode_me(s,'A') a as a
```

I got the error:

SemanticException [Error 10081]: UDTF's are not supported outside the SELECT clause, nor nested in expressions

I understand the error.
I do not understand how to make my code more compact.

Comment: I was able to solve it by removing the explode() from the macro body and keep only split() inside the macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by removing the explode() from the macro body and keep only split() inside the macro.